# Greyscale MSE Favicon

Tags: script, icons

This userscript is **obsolete** now that the icon has been changed to something entirely more sensible. It is preserved below for posterity, and also so I can keep the 60 rep you all graciously gave me for it.

> ### Preview
>
> [image]
>
> ### About
>
> When [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) *finally* split from [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) (yay!), the shiny new Meta's icon was revealed to be the same as the icon used for stackexchange.com. This makes it a bit hard to tell which tabs are on which site by scanning the tab list. (It also made my Firefox pinned tabs (SE, MSE, this site, MSE chat, SE chat) *very* homogenous.)
>
> This userscript exists solely to give Meta SE a more fetching greyscale icon to make it more different.
>
> #### License
>
> [**The MIT License**](http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT)
>
> #### Download
>
> [**Userscript**](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/michaelb958/11029969/raw/a39219d6a9ee4c4ac4c655bd367666452063e3df/msegreyicon.user.js)
>
> #### Platform
>
> Runs on any browser that jQuery supports (which is quite a few).
>
> ### Contact
>
> It's just me, [@michaelb958](https://stackexchange.com/users/1048581/michaelb958?tab=accounts). You can contact me by:
>
> - Commenting on or answering this post. This is the preferred mechanism for providing feedback or suggestions.
> - Pinging me on [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/). For general conversation and stuff.
> - Emailing me (email address available on [my GitHub profile](https://github.com/michaelb958)). For use in case of emergency.
>
> ### Code
>
> jQuery, with a dash of JavaScript.
>   [Github Gist!](https://gist.github.com/michaelb958/11029969)

Comment: Nice. [Here's a version that also changes the icons in the top bar.](https://gist.github.com/vyznev/11071156) (Ps. Have you already proposed officially changing the icon on MSE?)

Comment: @IlmariKaronen That would require me to think *before* coding. `:P`

Comment: OK, [I did it for you, then](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230061/make-the-mse-favicon-grayscale-like-all-other-meta-icons-are), you lazy bastard. ;-)